# Flutuar elemento a direta

Tags: html, css

Como eu poderia flutuar essa imagem para a direta sem quebrar a página?
nessa imagem, o css está dessa forma:

```
#centro-distribuicao {
    float: right;
    width: 550px;
}
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

Para o float funcionar corretamente você precisa adicionar uma div com o style clear: both; para não sobrescrever o conteúdo abaixo.
Fiz um modelo dá página Sobre Mirror Fashion como exemplo:

```
   <figure id="centro-distribuicao">
      <img src="https://s10.postimg.org/9dp0m5s6h/centro_distribuicao.png">
      <figcaption>Centro de distribuição da Mirror Fashion</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p> Nosso centro de distribuição fica em <a href="#">Jacarezinho, no Paraná</a>. De lá, saem 48 aviões quedistribuem nossos produtos às casas do mundo todo. Nosso centro de distribuição:</p>
    <p>Compre suas roupas e acessórios na Mirror Fashion. Acesse <a href="#">nossa loja</a> ou entre em <a href="#">contato</a> se tiver dúvidas. Conheça também nossa <a href="#">história</a> e nossos <a href="#">diferenciais</a>.</p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
```

Css:

```
<style>
   .clear {
     clear: both;
   }
   figure {
    width: 550px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F2EDED;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 12px 12px 10px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  #centro-distribuicao {
    float: right;
  }
</style>
```

Veja no exemplo: https://codepen.io/jamillerocha21/full/wWRJYg

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo, quando utilizei o clear:both. O meu css está um pouco diferente mas cheguei no mesmo resultado. Tem outra solução: colocar a imagem em baixo do h1 e usar o float no #centro-distribuicao.

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou colocar uma margem nela?

```
#centro-distribuicao {
    float: right;
    width: 550px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda, mas não deu certo.